# windows partition rotten following partition size change on a dual-boot Windows/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, multi-boot, nfs

I am stuck:
On a dual-boot Windows/Linux PC, in order to enlarge the boot partition which was running out of space to update the kernel, I wanted to move a Windows partition that had the system 32 using 'kde partition manager'.
After this, the partition is no longer NTFS and Windows is no longer able to read it and repair it. So Windows is no longer working and Grub is not detected by the BIOS (so Linux is no longer working either even if it has not been corrupted).
Looking at the hexadecimal, the Windows partition starts with a large number of zeros (on a few hundred lines) before seeing file contents...
Does anyone know what to do please?

Comment: Best: Restore from your last disk image. This is by far fastest and safest. Alternative: Salvage files and then reinstall Windows and Linux.

Comment: Moving system partitions is a bad idea. Especially Linux tools like parted, gpared are extremely terrible at moving/resizing NTFS compared to solutions such as MiniTool Partition Wizard, AOMEI Partition Assistant, EaseUS Partition Master, Macrorit Partition Expert...

Comment: @phuclv *Linux tools like parted, gpared are extremely terrible at moving/resizing NTFS compared* No, they aren't, they're as good as any other. The problem is always user error, including messing with an hibernated ("dirty") partition. What happens is some tools assume the users know what they're doing - not the case here - while others try to save users from themselves by not allowing certain operations. Other that that there's nothing wrong with the tools you mentioned for dealing with any supported file system.

Comment: @Fxfnet The best way to resize/move Windows partitions is doing it from Windows using Windows native tools. This however doesn't preclude knowing exactly what you're doing -and- having proper backups. Each and any operation HAS risks, ranging from very minimal to the situation you're in now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto no they're far worse. I've used all the above tools in so many PCs and ntfsresize (used by gparted) is the worst. gparted doesn't know to move only the non-overlapping regions and always move the entire partition. Other tools do that so not only they're significantly faster, they also greatly reduce the change of data loss/corruption. Of course users knowledge is required, but the tool is also important. In any case moving the system partition is a silly idea

Comment: @phuclv Again, if you're doing that with "dirty" partitions then it's plain and simple user error. But sure, as I commented above prefer doing it from Windows with native Windows tools. That said I've used Gparted and even Disks for resizing and/or moving non-hibernated "clean" NTFS partitions and never had a problem. If those tools were so bad as you say then all of the thousands of dual-boot setups with automatic Windows partitions resizing (shrinking) done any given hour of any given day would end up in tragedy and that objectively doesn't happen, we would have heard about it and we DON'T..

Comment: As a matter of fact, knowing that so many people ignore basic procedures, ignore hibernation (including Fast Startup), have errors in the partitions being managed and/or pending Windows updates and decide to do the Linux part anyway, **it's quite surprising how so few reported problems we actually see, here or anywhere in the interwebz**. So, please stop with the FUD.

Comment: @ChanganAuto who said that I do anything with dirty partitions? Moving a completely normal data partition takes forever with ntfsresize while Acronis partition wizard can do in a blink of an eye. And for dirty partitions ntfsresize will refuse to do while other tools can fix and move normally

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I finally reinstalled windows, hope I will be able to read data from the old partition image… thanks for all your contributions !

Comment: Good your problem's resolved :-) However, please note that answers are for providing answers only, not for thank-yous etc. You could maybe expand this to a proper answer following [this https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how SE sites differ from discussion forums.